# static クラス内でクラス.クラスメソッド名を実行したところ、エラーが出ます。理由がわかりません。

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで２点質問がございます。

1. メインクラス内で`ST_Test.testMethod(2);`を書くと、メソッドが実行されるのですが、staticクラスであるST_Testクラスで、`ST_Test.testMethod(2);`を書くと、コンパイルエラーがでます。
   エラー内容は以下の通りです。これはなぜ起こるのでしょうか？メインクラスで書くのと、staticクラス内で書くのとでは大きな違いでもあるのでしょうか？

   ```
   estmain.java:45: エラー: <identifier>がありません
       ST_Test.testMethod(2);
                         ^
   testmain.java:45: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
       ST_Test.testMethod(2);
                          ^
   エラー2個
   ```
2. 今回、ST_Testクラスはメインクラスでないため、

   ```
   static class ST_Test
   ```

   と書きましたが、staticを敢えて書かずに、「class ST_Test」とだけ描いても問題ないでしょうか？

   ```
   //インスタンスメソッドとstaticメソッドの違いを理解するプログラム
   public class Testmain {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           ST_Test.testMethod(2);
       }

       static class ST_Test{

           public static String S_STR = "S_STR";
           public String str = "str";int n;

           ST_Test.testMethod(2);

           public static void testMethod(int i) {
               System.out.println("i="+i);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**実行環境**

- openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: 質問中にソースコードを貼る際は、なるべく整形してからの方が読み手にとってより親切になると思います。 / 過去の質問でも明らかに不要と思われる空行が目立ち、読みにくいコードになっていました。今回は勝手ながら私の方で編集してみましたので、次回以降の参考にしてもらえればと思います。

Answer (score 2):

## コンパイルエラーの理由

Javaのクラスの中にメソッド呼び出しをいきなり書くことはできません。

```
static class ST_Test{
    public static String S_STR = "S_STR"; // ここはプロパティなのでOK
    public String str = "str";int n;      // ここもプロパティなのでOK

    ST_Test.testMethod(2);  // ここにメソッド呼び出しはNG
}
```

できないことをやろうとなさっているので、何がしたいのか不明ではありますが、コンパイルを通すように修正してみたものが下記です。

```
public class Testmain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ST_Test.testMethod(2);
        ST_Test.hoge();
    }

    static class ST_Test{
        public static String S_STR = "S_STR";
        public String str = "str";int n;

        public static void hoge() {
            ST_Test.testMethod(1); // 直接書けないのでhogeメソッドで包む。引数ももう一つの呼び出しと区別しやすいように 2から1へ変更
        }

        public static void testMethod(int i) {
            System.out.println("i="+i);
        }
    }
}
```

> メインクラス内でST_Test.testMethod(2);を書くと、メソッドが実行される

と表現されていますが、厳密には `Testmain`内の`mainメソッド`内で`ST_Test.testMethod(2);`を書いていますので、クラスの中にいきなりメソッド呼び出しをしているわけではありません。

> メインクラスで書くのと、staticクラス内で書くのとでは大きな違いでもあるのでしょうか？

よって、違いは、メソッドの中でメソッド呼び出しをしていたか、そうでないかです。`static`クラスであるかそうでないかは関係ありません。

## クラスにstaticは必要かどうか

> staticを敢えて書かずに、「class ST_Test」とだけ描いても問題ないでしょうか？

コンパイルが通るようになったので、`static class ST_Test`から`static`を削除してみるとどうなるか確認してみます。

そうすると下記のようなエラーが出ました。

```
Testmain.java:8: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Testmain.ST_Test
        public static String S_STR = "S_STR";
                             ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
Testmain.java:11: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Testmain.ST_Test
        public static void hoge() {
                           ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
Testmain.java:15: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Testmain.ST_Test
        public static void testMethod(int i) {
                           ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
```

ですので、`static` は必要なようです。

Answer (score 0):

質問2についてですが、staticは必要です。このプログラムはTestmainクラスのオブジェクトを生成しない状態で動いているので、Testmainクラスがインスタンシエイトされてからでないと使えないnon-staticなinner classをこの流れで呼び出すことはできません。

全体をnon-staticで書くのであれば例えば以下のようになります。

```
public class Testmain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testmain main = new Testmain();
        ST_Test st_test = main.new ST_Test();
        st_test.testmethod(2);
    }

    private class ST_Test {
        public void testmethod(int i) {
            System.out.println("i="+i);
        }
    }
}
```

お題が「インスタンスメソッドとstaticメソッドの違いを理解するプログラム」ということなので、納得されるまでいろいろコードをいじって掴むようにするのが良いと思います。最初のころは（人によっては）全部staticなプログラムを書いてしまいがちなのですが、あまり良い習慣ではないのでクラスとインスタンスの関係を把握しながらコードを書く癖をつけた方が良いです。

Comment: Testmain main = new Testmain();←ST_Testクラスのインスタンスを生成する前に、なぜこの1行が必要なのでしょうか？ST_Testクラスはstaticであれ、nonstaticであれ、あくまでもTestmainクラスの一部（付属している）という位置付けなのでしょうか？

Comment: non-staticなinner classはouter classのinstanceを介してでないとinstantiateできないのです。そういうものです。実際には単なるルールではなく背後には設計思想がありますが、難しければ最初は単なるルールとしてそういうものだと覚えるのも良いと思います。後々経験を積む中で理解できるようになるかも知れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。